# Haskell Partition with sets- parse error?

Tags: haskell

The partition has to be of the form:
partition :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> (Set a, Set a)

my code:

```
partition pred [] = []
partition pred (front : rest)
      = partition pred rest, if pred front
      = (front : rest), otherwise
```

however i get a error: 
error: parse error on input `,'
    |
192 |       = partition pred rest, if pred front

anyone can tell me the fix if possible?

Comment: Unless you have some special extension, that is *not* how guards look like.

Comment: Furthermore the types do not match, since your function is supposed to return a 2-tuple of `Set`s.

Answer (score 5):

```
= partition pred rest, if pred front
```

This isn't valid Haskell.  Where did you learn this?  Stop using that resource.  The guard should look like:

```
| pred front = partition pred rest
```

But, as noted in the comments, that code isn't going to do what you want - you're throwing away `front`.  For that matter, what is `front`? Let's see

```
(front : rest)
```

Well this isn't a set at all, it's just a list. OK fine, in your world Sets are lists.  But you need to put `front` in the set that matches the predicate which is part of the answer you'll get from `partition pred rest`.

There are more type errors but hopefully this gets you going.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here:

1. first of all, the syntax you use is a bit similar to *guards*, but not the correct syntax;
2. the types do not match, your function is supposed to return a 2-tuple of `Set`s, so you need to wrap the result in a 2-tuple. At first sight it looks like your implementation is more related to `filter` than to `partition`; and
3. the items are supposed to be `Set`s, not *lists*.

For a *list*, the `partition` function looks like:

```
partition :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> ([a], [a])
partition pred [] = ([], [])
partition pred (x:xs)
    | pred x = ((x:y1), y2)
    | otherwise = (y1, (x:y2))
    where (y1, y2) = partition pred xs
```

I leave it as an exerise to convert the above code to work with a `Set`.